# iOS Printing Custom Paper

Tags: ios, printing

I would like to ask for advise about technical issue when printing to custom paper size 6,2Inch*8Inch from iOS application. In this case iPad application.

The paper size provided by ios, only 4 paper size. so when my paper size is different, the continuity printer to next page will appear not fit.

Comment: The paper size provided by ios, only 4 paper size. so when my paper size is different, the continuity printer to next page will appear not fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says:

> Paper sizes and their designations are locale- and printer-specific. Most applications use the default UIPrintPaper object created by UIKit for a print job. However, if an application has special requirements for content areas, the delegate of the UIPrintInteractionController object can return a UIPrintPaper object representing the preferred paper size.

Unfortunately it looks like you can't choose just any paper size; your UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate has to choose one of the given paper sizes. The best you can do is to call [`+bestPaperForPageSize:withPapersFromArray:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPrintPaper_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIPrintPaper/bestPaperForPageSize%3awithPapersFromArray%3a) to find the paper size best suited to your content.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I found so far. So the conclusion is iOS not provide custom paper size, but they will fit to the given paper size. :(

Answer (score 0):

This is a late reply but maybe could help others

How about implementing:

```
 - (UIPrintPaper *)printInteractionController:(UIPrintInteractionController*)printInteractionController choosePaper:(NSArray *)paperList
```

and then create a custom CGSize using:

```
CGSize custompapersize = CGSizeMake(6,2 * 72.0, 8.0 * 72.0);
```